# Intel UHD 630 graphics card is compatible with i5 and Ultra Wide Display,

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, cpu, resolution

I have a PC, DELL OptiPlex 7090 Micro with Intel® Core™ i5-10500T and an integrated graphics card UHD 630, that I use for visualizing several camera stream from a CCTV system (10 cameras at very low frame rate: 15fps). I would like to upgrade my monitor to an Ultra Wide monitor with aspect ratio 32:9 and a resolution 3840x1080, Samsung CHG9 series. I have verify that maximum supported resolution of the intel core graphics card and I have found that it's 4096 x 2160, which is lower than the monitor resolution. Anyhow I'm not 100% sure that the monitor resolution 3840x1080 will be supported by the PC, how can I be sure about that (for instance that in the Windows10 setting I will found a correct display resolution)?  Do you think that the monitor resolution will be compatible with the PC graphics card?

Comment: Your computer has DisplayPort 1.4, which is capable of up to 4k 120Hz. Your processor can do up to 4096 x 2304 60Hz over DisplayPort 1.4. Both of these are higher resolution than your monitor, so it should be absolutely no problem.

Comment: The display resolution won't show up in settings until you connect a display capable of that resolution. You may possibly have to make some changes in the Intel graphics control software as well.

Comment: Right-click the desktop and choose *Display settings > Advanced display settings > Display adapter properties for Display 1 > Adapter > List All Modes*. Do you see 3840x1080 listed?

Comment: @harrymc I have tried your suggestion, anyhow I have seen that the resolutions changes based on the display I select. On my current configuration I have two display with different resolutions, if I select the display with lower resolution I found that some resolutions are missing respect to the other higher-resolution display

Comment: The above lists all the modes possible for the *display adapter*, **not** taking the monitor in account. If you can't see your resolution, then the *adapter* itself is incapable of using it, no matter the monitor.

Comment: @harrymc, I try to replicate what you have suggested with a laptop connected to an eternal monitor. As you can see from the images https://ibb.co/0BP2tfw and https://ibb.co/Jy5LJNW it seems that the values changes based on the display resolution. In this case maybe if I will connect a display with higher resolution I will discover new option